# Inversion from "[past verb] so adverb" to "so adverb did"

Tags: grammar, inversion

> One of London Zoo's recent advertisements caused me some irritation, **so patently did** it distort reality.

I don't know what to do to understand this phrase..

I guessed this sentence as "The advertisement caused me irritation. It distorted reality." I'm not sure.

But I don't know how it can be 1 sentence. And What is the meaning and usage of "so patently did"? I know 'patently' means 'obviously'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply rearranged word order. That sentence means:

> One of London Zoo's recent advertisements caused me some irritation, **it distorted reality so patently**.

It's common to do an subject-verb inversion when the adverb is put before. Another common example is "*Little did I know*":

> I was speaking ill of Fred; **little did I know** that he was right behind me, listening in.‎ ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/little#Adverb))

Meaning "*I didn't know*", or "*I knew little about the fact that...*"

Comment: Then is there any difference between normal order and rearranged order?

Comment: Plus, can two sentences be connected by comma?

Comment: @TINGCHOE I'd say it's just style. And what do you mean, "two sentences"? If there's a coma it's only one sentence. Are you talking about the semicolon perhaps? ( ; )

Comment: I mean, if you replace comma to period, the sentence becomes two sentences.

Comment: @TINGCHOE In your sentence? Yes, I think you could use a period instead of a coma. The coma is better because it links a cause to its consequence, but it's not incorrect to use a period.